# Hide file extension in document based app - DocumentGroup & UIDocumentBrowser

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller, documentgroup

I've been working on a document-based app for well over 12 months now. It's out on the store, and everything is going well so far except for something I have been unable to solve since iOS 13.

The built-in file viewer shows all my apps files with the extension. I've rewritten the app in SwiftUI using DocumentGroup but also saw the problem with UIDocumentBrowser.

Even Apple's own [Particles demo app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/building_a_document_browser_app_for_custom_file_formats) has this issue.

I figure that it's likely a bug and there's nothing I can do about it, but I also haven't seen anyone else talking about this. So it could equally be something that I'm doing wrong.

Is there possibly a setting somewhere I need to change?

- I had a look at `NSFileExtensionHidden` but that is already set to true.
- Looking at other files in the browser - in my app - shows that those have their extension hidden. But that could just be because my app doesn't support opening them.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `hasHiddenExtensionKey`? It's a URLResourceKey.

Comment: No go on that one

Answer (score 0):

If your app's file have a custom extension, have you [Defined that as a File Type for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app)?

If not, that could be a reason why document browser considers it part of file name without extension.

Comment: Yeah as far as I can tell, it's all set up correctly.